# Mounting a partition in the /cdrom mount point

Tags: installation, debian, mount

I was installing [CrunchBang Linux](http://crunchbang.org/) (#!) today, and everything was going pretty well, until I got to the point where files are copied from installation media to HDD.

I had burned the `.iso` to `/dev/sda6` for reasons, and I can run the installer just fine. The problem is that the installer tries to mount the CD-ROM for installation, but it obviously does not exist. I can enter the a path instead, so that seems fixed. But no, I can't mount `/dev/sda6`, or any file system. The command

```
mount -t ext3 /dev/sda6 /cdrom
```

returns

> no such device.

I am really, really stuck so I would appreciate any help!

see:
[Unable to mount hard drives in Debian installer shell](https://superuser.com/questions/646599/unable-to-mount-hard-drives-in-debian-installer-shell?newreg=e329fbcd6a0c41049c6217b9f820c124) , but I'm on a different goal than him

Comment: What is output of `ls /dev`?

Comment: or `mount` or `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: And, by the way, per [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount): The argument following the `-t` is used to indicate the filesystem type. You are specifying device right after `-t`.

Comment: It's typically `/dev/cdrom ` not just `/cdrom `.

Comment: @Nikolay /dev/sda6 exists. I used mount -t ext3 /dev/sda6 /cdrom, but got the same error. /cdrom exists.

Comment: Ok, got it. Will be good if you can update your post with output of `ls /dev`, `mount`, `sudo fdisk -l` as we asked you before in first two comments. It is little bit hard to debug without seeing the stuff...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, (please correct me if I am wrong), what you are trying to do is to burn the iso image to a partition of your current hard disk, and then boot off that.

If this is so, you can easily boot off this partition. It seems, from what you say, that you have already extracted the iso image to /dev/sda6, `i.e.`, you have not simply copied the iso file but you have extracted it. Then you can proceed as follows:

1. make /dev/sda6 bootable; you can use gparted for that (easier to handle than fdisk which would otherwise do just as well).
2. run `update-grub` from within Debian. Grub will find the new, bootable partition, an add it to the Grub boot menu.

Now you can boot your pc the usual way, then choose the bootable partition sda6, and proceed to install the new OS. Just make sure that the partition on which you wish to install the new OS, and the one on which you have the iso, are different: you cannot instal crunchbang on the very same partition /dev/sda6.

Edit:

to answer your query about how to make a partition bootable: as sudo, issue the command

```
  fdisk /dev/sda
```

at the prompt, hit `a`, you will get a reply:

```
  Partition number (1-6):
```

and you can now choose the partition number to make bootable (6, in your case). Now hit `w` for "write changes to disk", then `q`for "quit", and you are done.

Comment: /dev/sda6 appears in the grub boot menu. I can't seem to find instructions to make a partition bootable.

Comment: @Atsch please read the Edit to my answer

Comment: i only get partition number (1-4) :( the partition definetly exists in gparted

Comment: How is this not worth An upvote??

Answer (score 0):

Try `mount /dev/sda6 /cdrom` without the `-t` option.

Comment: nope, I get a different error. The actual command was mount -t ext3 /dev/sda6 /cdrom, but I misspelled the OP